# Reading value from a field on another tab

Tags: android

First day of Android development so forgive any ignorance.

My MainActivity class has the following code:

```
    // Create the tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, DisplayActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Display")
                .setIndicator("Display")
                .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SettingsActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Settings")
                .setIndicator("Settings")
                .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

I want to retrieve the value of a field from settings in the display tab. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use "shared preferences"?  When the field is set, update the preference.  When you need it in display, read the preference.  See [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) for more on this.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2-3 ways for doing same
1. Using Variables on Application level
2. Using Shared Pref.

Create Class which extends Application having getter setter method.

setting data in one Activity

```
Times myApp = ((Times)getApplication()); // where Times is my getter setter class
                                                        which extends Applicaton 
myApp.setHour1(5);
```

getting Data in another activity

```
Times myApp = ((Times)getApplication());
int variable = (myApp.getHour1());
```

Dont forget to mention ur Application level class name in Manifest file like :

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:name=".Times"
    >
```

Best of Luck

Answer (score 0):

I use a slightly different approach then the one suggested by others on the post.

I put the common data object to be shared across the activities in different tabs in the intent that is passed while adding the tab. In your example, the code using this approach would look like:

```
// Create the tabs
MyObject myObj = new MyObj(); 
//MyObject should implement android.os.Parcelable interface
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, DisplayActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("myObjKey", myObj);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Display")
            .setIndicator("Display")
            .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SettingsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("myObjKey", myObj);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Settings")
            .setIndicator("Settings")
            .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

In the individual activity the same object can be obtained from intent that is supplied to the activity when it it launched.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.somecontentlayout);
    MyObject myObj = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("myObjKey");
}
```

Hope this helps.